# Adding a click event to the ColVis list items

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm working on a web based tool using asp.net and Javascript with Jquery to implement various tables and make them user friendly. For this purpose I am using the lovely [Datatables](http://datatables.com) plugin with its extension ColVis for the option of hiding selected columns. What I am now trying to do is to add another .click event to list items in the list generated by ColVis, but I am having a real trouble selecting the correct element with Jquery for attaching the function.

This is the HTML generated by ColVis.

```
<ul class="ColVis_collection ui-buttonset ui-buttonset-multi" style="...">
    <li class="colVis_select ui-button ui-state-default">...</li>
    <li class="colVis_select ui-button ui-state-default">...</li>
    ...
</ul>
```

And so on.

What I have tried is this:

```
 $(".ul").on("click","li" , function (event) {
                Cookies.set('columnsWebform', readingHeaders());
            })
```

To be as general as possible. But I still cannot get it to respond to clicks.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT WITH SOLUTION**

As Joel pointed out the selector is wrong. That was not the whole problem though. The HTML code for the list was not generated until a button was pressed.

```
<button class="ColVis_Button ColVis_MasterButton">
```

Thus connecting the creation of the clickevent listeners to the pressing of this button solved the problem.

```
 $(".ColVis_MasterButton").click(function () {
            $("ul").on("click", "li", function () {
                Cookies.set('columnsWebform', readingHeaders());
            })
        });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can post your solution as an answer and accept it, that will mark the question as closed.

Comment: Hi @Gyrocode.com, I've used your code but it's still not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the working solution. First off the selector needs to be for the tag ul and not the class ul.

```
$("ul").on("click", "li", function () {
            Cookies.set('columnsWebform', readingHeaders());
        })
```

This did not solve the whole problem though.
The HTML code for the list was not generated until a button was pressed.

```
<button class="ColVis_Button ColVis_MasterButton">
```

Thus connecting the creation of the clickevent listeners to the pressing of this button solved the problem.

```
$(".ColVis_MasterButton").click(function () {
        $("ul").on("click", "li", function () {
            Cookies.set('columnsWebform', readingHeaders());
        })
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `$('ul')`.

Currently you are selecting the class `ul` by using `.ul` not the `ul` tag.

Comment: Yes , I realised that problem shortly after I posted this, but the problem persists despite selecting the tag correctly. But I believe I have found out why. 

The HTML code is not actually generated until a certain button is clicked. Since my "click" code is excuted during document.ready , the HTML doesn't exist yet. So am going to try and connect the click event listeners after the HTML has been generated. 

Thank you for your quick answer.

Comment: Yes, thats the way to go. Bind the event after the HTML is generated.

Comment: That worked out perfectly, updated the post with the solution. (should that possibly be written as an Answer to the question instead?) Thanks again.

Comment: Post it as an answer.